# How do i replace blank spaces with letters in VI?

Tags: vi

I have to replace 2 or more blanks with "XX", how can i accomplish this?

I don't know the wildcard for blank spaces.

Answer (score 6):

The regular expression that will match two or more spaces is `'   *'`, so in `vi`, type

```
:%s/   */XX/g
```

To explain, thats

`:    to enter ex command mode`
`%    apply this change to all lines`
`s    replace everything between the first and second slashes with everything between the second and third`
`<sp><sp><sp>* two spaces, followed by zero or more spaces`
`g    apply the change to every instance on the line`

(I only had two spaces in the regex originally, which would have replaced every string of contiguous spaces in the file with XX, including single spaces)

Comment: `:%s/sleep 1/sleep 30/g`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** As pointed out by rojomoke in the comments, this solution only works with Vim and not with the old Vi editor.

You can use:

```
:%s/\s\{2,}/XX/g
```

- `\s` match a whitespace
- `\{2,}` match two or more

This way you will replace by `XX` any succession of two or more whitespaces.

Comment: @rojomoke: You are right. Maybe that doesn't deserve a downvote but simply an edit precising that it works only with vim? As vim is pretty common today I guess that still might help another user one day.

Comment: My bad as the vote happened at the same time as your comment and the view count didn't changed I assumed it was you, sorry for that.